# Insertion sort array of structure by 2 fields

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort

I am making an uno card game with structure of card with fields:

```
struct card
{
    int rank 
    char *color  
    char *action. 
}
```

I am able to make it sort by color with insertion. I wonder how could I first sort the array of uno card by color, then sort the rank of each color.

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far? It's quite hard to answer such a question without seeing the specifics.

Comment: If you have a condition `color1 < color2`, you can change that to `color1 < color2  || (color1 == color2 && rank1 < rank2)`.

Comment: ^This, is the solution.

Comment: Thank you Bo Persoson, this is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Bo Persoson, this is the solution to my question

```
void sort(card *a, int length) {
int j;
for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    j = i;
    while (j > 0 && a[j].color < a[j - 1].color || (a[j].color == a[j - 1].color && a[j].rank < a[j - 1].rank)) {
        swap(&a[j], &a[j - 1]);
        j--;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the structure is called card and c1 and c2  are two pointers to objects of the structure.

In this case you should use the following condition to compare elements of the array

```
int comparison( card *c1, card *c2 )
{
    int color_cmp = strcmp( c1->color, c2->color ); 
    return color_cmp < 0 || ( color_cmp == 0 && c1->rank < c2->rank );
}
```

This predicate is considered as a boolean predicate. If you need a comparison function thet will be used in the standard algorithm `qsort` then you have to change it such a way that it returns -1, 0 or 1.

For example

```
int comparison( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    const card *c1 = ( const card * )p1;
    const card *c2 = ( const card * )p2;

    int color_cmp = strcmp( c1->color, c2->color ); 

    if ( color_cmp < 0 )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( color_cmp > 1 )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    { 
        return ( c2->rank < c1->rank ) - ( c1->rank < c2->rank );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are overloading the `operator <`, you should implement a condition that compares the color of the cards and their rank. Since you want that the primary sorting criteria will be the color you should check that one first. I would implement it something like this:

```
int colorCompareResult = strcmp(card1.color, card2.color);
if (colorCompareResult < 0)
    return true;
else if (colorCompareResult == 0 && card1.rank < card2.rank)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```