# Sorting Linked List with Two Parameters in C

Tags: c

The linked list contain two types of data - int count and float rank. The list needs to be sorted in descending order based firstly on count and then on rank. I have sorted the list based on count, but it appears I don't get the process completely.

I understand that if current count is equal to the next count, then compare rank and insert node with higher rank.

I have changed the code after the comment, however it does output data correctly (does not sort by the rank). How can I fix it?

Sorted list by the first parameter (what I currently get):

```
2, 0.152009
2, 0.077676
2, 0.092575
2, 0.157685
1, 0.262355
1, 0.184311
1, 0.073388
```

Expected output after sorting list by the second parameter:

```
2, 0.157685
2, 0.152009
2, 0.092575
2, 0.077676
1, 0.262355
1, 0.184311
1, 0.073388
```

My code:

```
typedef struct node {
    int count;
    float rank;
    struct node *next;
} NodeT; 

void insertionSort(NodeT **head) {
    
    NodeT *sorted = NULL;
    NodeT *current = *head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        NodeT *next = current->next;
        sortedInsert(&sorted, current);
        current = next;
    }
    *head = sorted;
}

void sortedInsert(NodeT **head, NodeT *new) {

    NodeT *current;

    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->count <= new->count) {
        new->next = *head;
        *head = new;

    } else {
        current = *head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {

            /* Should second parameter check go here? */

            if (current->next->count > new->count) {
                current = current->next;

            } else if (current->next->count == new->count) {

                while (current->next != NULL && current->next->rank > new->rank) {
                    current = current->next;
                } 
            }

        }
        new->next = current->next;
        current->next = new;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean exactly? Have you tried debugging your code? You'll learn a more by stepping through it in a debugger and inspecting your variables. And do post an [mcve], please.

Comment: @jwdonahue I have described the problem with sample of expected output and current output, and stated that I was not able to sort by the second parameter with current code and asked how can I fix it. What other details are you looking for?

Comment: Read [ask], [mcve] and https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Can you write out your intended algorithm in english? I find it helps to describe an algorithm before I try to write it.

Answer (score 4):

The "correct" way is probably to write a comparison function to avoid the two nested `while` loops.

```
int compare_nodes(NodeT *n1, NodeT *n2)
{
    if (n1->count < n2->count)
        return -1;
    if (n1->count > n2->count)
        return 1;
    if (n1->rank < n2->rank)
        return -1;
    if (n1->rank > n2->rank)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Now you should have a much easier time implementing the insert function.

Answer (score 1):

In [Is there a way to sort structs by multiple variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637855/is-there-a-way-to-sort-structs-by-multiple-variables-in-c) is an example that uses `qsort` with a defined compare function (`cmp()`). It implements the nodes as struct, in `main()` the list is created...

An example for *insertion sort* is in [Insertion sort array of structure by 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044559/insertion-sort-array-of-structure-by-2-fields)

Comment: Given that this seems to be the OP's homework assignment, and they appear to be attempting to write an insertion sort algorithm, it's probably safe to assume that a qsort would not be an acceptable answer.